# directory listing Ban

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder where I am uploading my documents and give user options to download these documents on the basis of permission with each document.

I want to restrict user to directly access the folder and downloading the file.

I have done the direct access listing ban with htaccess but if I add the document name  in the URL, its downloading the same file.
How can I forbid this download access?

Thanks for your all help.
Umar

Comment: I have added a .htaccess file in the folder where I store my files and the htaccess code is 


RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Ban directory browsing
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
#allow in office only
<limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</limit>

Answer (score 0):

I have used **mod_auth_token** before to protect folders from direct downloading.
It is very efficient, and easy to use.

http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/